# Calling a .net 2.0 method from a .net 4.5 test causes a RemotingException

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-2.0, .net-4.5, remoting

In my solution I have a test project using .net 4.5 that calls methods on a class library project written in .net 2.0.

I have successfully called many methods (all functions), but one method (a Sub) is giving me a problem.  It throws a RemotingException.

```
The method '...' was not found on the interface/type.
```

Intellisense works properly when I instantiate MyType in the test class.  It's only when I try running the test that it throws the exception.

I have deleted the reference in my test project and readded it.  I have added the reference as a "Solution" reference as well as a "Browse" reference.

**Update 1**

I switched my Sub to a Function and still received the RemotingException.  The method I am calling in the .net 2.0 project is a new method that I added after I initially created the Test project and tests for all of the other methods.

**Update 2**

The class library is defined as such:

```
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)>
<Transaction(TransactionOption.Required)>
Public Class MyComponent
    Inherits ServicedComponent
```

And in the test, I am referencing the class like this:

```
<TestClass()>
Public Class MyTests

    Protected Property MyCom As MyComponent

    Public Sub New()
        MyCom = New MyComponent()
    End Sub
```

When I run my test, MyCom is created as this object instead of just an instance of MyComponent.

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy
```

Comment: Rebooting caused things to start working again.  For some reason my proxy wasn't updating even when clean/rebuilding my entire solution (no projects were skipped in the build process).  I'm not going to post this as an official answer because I would still love to know why the proxy was holding on to the old implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for anyone else that happens upon this issue, here is what I discovered.

In fact, rebooting wasn't the thing that solved my problem.  It was that I had also re-registered my new dll in my locally running Component Services.

When you are testing a ServicedComponent and you create an instance of that ServicedComponent, it actually wraps a Remoting Proxy around the component that is currently running in COM+, and NOT the actual class that you're thinking you are debugging.  Initially this wasn't an issue for me, but then I decided that I shouldn't be referencing my dll found in bin\debug directly from COM+, so I copied and moved it to another location.  I did this because my build was hanging often when I would make changes to my ServicedComponent and rebuild my solution.  Apparently when you build a ServicedComponent it attempts to put it into COM+ locally if there's not already a component of the same name already running there.

So by moving my dll and fixing my build hangup, I inadvertantly caused this issue.  It's cool though because it led me to a much deeper understanding of how to test ServicedComponents.

I have since recreated my component in COM+ and am once again referencing the one in bin\debug.  Which is nicely hanging when I build without shutting down the com application.  It's a nice reminder letting me know that I'm actually testing against a real COM component in its own address space and not just an instance of my class that's in managed memory.

Cheers!